# Method is getting invoked with out calling

Tags: asp.net

I am getting following Error when trying to convert the report data into PDF.
For the first time it's working fine, but while clicking the PDF button second time I'm getting following error while debugging. It's showing output Server Error in '/' Application error is getting displayed:.

> DeclaringMethod =
>   '((System.RuntimeType)((System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo)((System.Web.HttpApplication)sender).Events.head.handler.Method).DeclaringType).DeclaringMethod'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: Hi, you should post youre code here to be easier to judge. 
No one has clear imagin from what you have done until you post it here.
Thanx

Comment: Can you post the code you are having this issue?